# Access Sinatra settings from Minitest test_helper

Tags: ruby, sinatra, settings, minitest, helper

I am trying to access a variable defined in Sinatra settings from my test helper with no luck. This is my code:

#### Main app:

```
require 'sinatra'

set :foo, 'bar'

# use settings.foo in the routes
```

#### tests/test_helper.rb

```
ENV['RACK_ENV'] = 'test'

require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'rack/test'

module Minitest
  class Spec
    include Rack::Test::Methods

    def app
      Sinatra::Application
    end

    before do
      # do something with settings.foo
    end
  end
end
```

I have tried `Sinatra::Application.settings.foo` and also `app.settings.foo` but none work.

I have also tried adding a helper method like the one below:

#### lib/helpers/settings_helper.rb

```
module SettingsHelper
  def foo
    settings.foo
  end
end

helpers SettingsHelper
```

This works inside `app`, but again doesn't work inside `test_helper`. I tried requiring `settings_helper.rb` in `test_helper`. Also added an `include`. None of this worked.

Does anybody know what am I doing wrong?

Happy holidays

Comment: I think you might be confusing unit tests and specs, it looks like you mixed their syntax. Check for instance this link https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/getting-started-with-minitest where you can see that the spec should be in a `describe` clause, not in a `module`. And most likely, your Sinatra app's main.rb (or equivalent) will have to be `require`d before that, and `settings` will be in scope.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will work with a [classic style](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Sinatra::Base%20-%20Middleware,%20Libraries,%20and%20Modular%20Apps) app. But with a modular app you can do `MyApp.set :foo, 'bar'`. So you could try `Sinatra::Application.set :foo, 'bar'`

Hope this helps.